# Dependency and workspace projects

Tags: eclipse, maven, workspace

I have a Maven project called Utils that i'm working on. I also have another project, called A, that uses classes of Utils. So, I've added a dependency to Utils in the POM of A. I precise that the two projects are not installed in the local repository (or another private repository). When I try to package the project A, I get an error because Maven tries to get the Utils project from the local repository and central repository, but it's not there. I don't want to install the project because it's not final, i don't want to give it a version because there is no release.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Maven plugin on Eclipse provides this possibility. And there is no need to install the artifacts corresponding to the active projects in the local repository. It seems that the plugin considers the workspace as a second local repository (you can see this using the Maven repositories view). First, the Workspace resolution feature must be enabled (Right click on the project then under Maven). When I want to run the project, I use Run configurations wizard, and Resolve workspace must be checked.

Is it a good solution? I don't know if it just seems to work or if it really works.

Thanks

Comment: Finally, it works for me and no need to install the projects in the repository. The workspace may be considered as a local repository by eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to install the project into local repository. Just use `mvn install` in the Utils' project folder. Anytime you do `install` it will be replaced by newest in your local repo.

But don't deploy it, it means others could use it. In comparison, your local repo is used only by you.

Comment: In my case, i don't want to install the artifact in the remote repository. I also want to forbid this operation. But i'm wondering how it's possible that everyone has the possibility to deploy an artifact in the remote repository of Maven (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)?

Comment: `mvn install` installs the artifact in the local repository (on your hard drive, the `.m2` folder of your user profile directory). repo1.maven.org is basically for open-source public libraries. If your company needs a repo shared between developers - you should install your own repo, google for _Artifactory_ or _Nexus_.

Comment: Yes, but i have my workspace with many projects i'm working on. Following the previous example, everytime I change the Utils code, I need to reinstall the artifact even where the app is not released.

Comment: Yes, after any changes in Utils just run `mvn install` for it. That's all you need to do. It's nothing to do with releases. Why do you think it's somehow wrong? There are `mvn deploy` and `mvn release` things for it.

Comment: Because it seems heavy to do this everytime, what you do if you have project A that depends on project B that depends on C? Would you run mvn install for C then for B then for A? And this everytime the code of C changes?!

Comment: No, if code of X is not changed, you don't need install X. Only in some situations if dependencies were changed. The maven favours project-based development. You have to make project X, make test cases for it, deploy it, release, then work with next project Y, keeping X untouched. Otherwise, you could work with project A, changing C and it unexpectedly breaks project D which also depends on C.

Comment: Okay. Did you hear about the ability of Eclipse to scan the workspace for use with Maven?